# Managing where an ‘and’ or a ‘,’ (comma) are inserted using a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

My difficulty is making a correct sentence structure with sentence components. In particular when Excel should use an ‘**and**’ or a ‘**,**’(comma).

I'm creating an automated report using Excel. I've built a spreadsheet that is looking at regions (10+) and the projects they all have (Projects A to F) and then populates a table for each region telling me whether a project has increased, decreased or no change.

I have managed to create a formula that places the ',' and 'and' correctly, but only if I have over 2 Projects represented in my sentences. Unfortunately it fails if there 2..

Below is an example of the table.

I've clicked in H7 to show the formula structure. It works when referring to Column G but not when referring to Column E or I.

[image: Example of the table]

My report will include a concatenation formula that will simply point to

```
concatenate(D3,E3,D4,E4,D5,E5,D6,E6,D7,E7,D8,E8)
```

which should create:

- “For Region 1 we have seen an increase in Project A **and** Project D.
- “There has been a decrease in Project C **,** Project E **and** Project F”
- "There is no change in Project B".

I am struggling to understand how to to make it include 'and' if there are only 2 entries.

Any pointers are gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell, but I think your example will also break for any sentence of 4 or more projects.

You can try concatenating all the project names with a comma and space and then use `SUBSTITUTE(haystack, needle, newvalue, n-th instance)`

If you do not have a trailing comma at the end, then the *n*-th instance is going to be the project count, less one. If you do have a trailing comma always, just trim it off beforehand.

So: concatenate, trim trailing comma if needed, substitute the last comma with "and", and then prefix with your "There has been..."

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll being trying it out on my spreadsheet.

Comment: I ended up with `=IFERROR(IF(E9<=1,[MyConcatenatedCel],SUBSTITUTE([MyConcatenatedCel],", "," and ",E9-1)),"")`. This managed to give me the results I was scratching my head looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

using VBA

project names can't contain comma ','

```
Function mCombine(mRange As Range) As String
    Dim mResult As String, mSize As Long

    For Each mCell In mRange
        If mCell <> "" Then mResult = mResult & mCell & " , "
    Next mCell

    mResult = Left(mResult, Len(mResult) - 3)
    mSize = Len(mResult) - (Len(Split(mResult, ",")(UBound(Split(mResult, ",")))) + 1)

    mCombine = Left(mResult, mSize - 1) & Replace(mResult, ",", "and", mSize)
End Function
```

Comment: I hadn't considered VBA because of my inadequacies with the language. I'm not sure if I understand correctly: is mRange referring to D3:I8? And the 3 in mResult is the three headings 'increased', 'decreased' and 'no movement'?

Comment: You can use `Join()` (the opposite of split) instead of `for each` + remove trailing comma. (at least in VBA)